# std::find : finding exact string c++ in a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, file, search

i want to use std::find() to see if an id exists in a file, example:

```
    //file:
    2467
    435
    24667
```

here is the function:

```
bool idInFile(string argId)
{

    std::ifstream anchorFile("anchors");
    string line;
    if(!anchorFile )//file not opened or empty
    {
        //cout << "file cannot be opened" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    anchorFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    if(anchorFile.tellg() == 0)
    {
        //cout << "file is empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    anchorFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while(getline(anchorFile, line))
    {
            std::size_t found = line.find(argId);
            if (found!=std::string::npos)
                    return true;
    }


    return false;
}
```

int this case: if i try to search the id 246, the function returns true because of the "2467" that contains "246", i need it to return true if only the id "246" exist in a line.

Comment: 1) Could use a regex: `^246$`.  2) Could check that `line.length() == 3`.  3) Use an indexed lookup...

Comment: i don't have boost installed, i'm coding in a debian machine, and i highly prefer having a solution with std::find(), ty for your answer btw :)

Comment: um... why would you need boost for regex? ugh.  2) would be easy to do without additional libraries...  (Your question really isn't clear as to the line is `id 126`, `id:126` or just `126`.  I assumed the latter.  3) was just to point out if you're simply looking for what is an id, file-scan is probably not the best solution. 4) make the search-string be `"\n246\n"`.

Comment: the file contains 1 id per line, the id is not an int it's a string, it can be 124arb ... 
when i execute idInFile("246"); it returns true despite that "246" is not in the file but "2467"

Comment: 1) Your design is wrong.  2) `line[found + argId.length()] > '9' // match is good.` <-- yes that's an oversimplification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basic_string::find` finds a *substring*, per [its documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

In this case you want an exact match; use [`basic_string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) or `==` instead (the latter uses `compare` internally).

Comment: i completly forgot about using the == operator, it's so much easier, i feel ashamed now :3

Comment: @Reda that can't possibly work if you have a line with `"246abc"` in it.

Comment: if(line == argId)
     return true;
return false;
where is the problem @ebyrob

Comment: @ebyrob: what do you mean by that? Of course it will work (and it will report "not equal" for the example `246`, just as intended).

Comment: whatever... @Reda wrote:  "the file contains 1 id per line, the id is not an int it's a string, it can be 124arb ... when i execute idInFile("246"); it returns true despite that "246" is not in the file but "2467" –  Reda 16 mins ago" ---- ie: line is: `"124arb"`  But yes, that was a departure from what is in the question...